# How to start a new thread in Flask? Thread can only be started once

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, raspberry-pi

I am using the Flask webframe to control a sensor (start and stop scanning) which is connected to a Raspberry Pi 3. Once I stop scanning (as the Event is set), I cannot start a new thread because the thread can only be started once. So any tip to start a new thread with a different variable name? or any alternatives?

```
import thread
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, redirect, render_template

def scan(number, duration):
    #Scanner scanning with 2 parameters

class LoopThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, event):
        super(LoopThread,self).__init__()
        self.name = name #can this use as a global variable?
        self.event = event
        self.number = 20
        self.duration = 1

    def run(self):
        print('Starting Thread-'+ str(self.name))
        while not self.event.wait(timeout=1.0):
            self.loop_process()

    def loop_process(self):
        scan(self.number, self.duration)

app = Flask(__name__)

stopevent = threading.Event()
thread = LoopThread(1, stopevent) #what can I change here?

@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("home page")
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/start")
def start():
    thread.start() #how do I change the function variable name everytime?
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route("/stop")
def stop():
    stopevent.set() #stop the senseor scanning
    thread.join()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution is to instantiate your thread in functions, assuming you can only have one running:

```
stopevent = None
thread = None

@app.route("/")
def index():
    print("home page")
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/start")
def start():
    global stopevent, thread
    if thread is not None:
        return redirect...
    stopevent = threading.Event()
    thread = LoopThread(1, stopevent) #what can I change here?
    thread.start() #how do I change the function variable name everytime?
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route("/stop")
def stop():
    global stopevent, thread
    if thread is None:
        return redirect....
    stopevent.set() #stop the senseor scanning
    thread.join()
    stopevent = None
    thread = None
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

This will allow you to start and stop your threads many times - but it will not allow several parallel threads. If this is what you want, then you need something else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But after trying your suggestion the scanner keep running and won'stop although I wanted to stop it in Flask. Btw once I comment out the if statement, it works! TQ